# Change colour of H3 tag onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header

I want to change the color of my h3 tags (3 of them in total) to red with the onclick event, then change it back to the original color once another h3 tag has been selected.

The now selected h3 tag becomes red.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('p.order').on('click', function() { 
        $('h3').css('color', 'red');
    }); 
});
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 class="alert"><p class="order">Orders</p></h3>
    <h3 class="cut"><p class="restaurant"> Restaurant</p></h3>
    <h3 class="icon"><p class="Account"> Account</p></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#accordion h3').on('click', function() {
        $('#accordion h3').css('color', 'black');
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/v9Lsxd5p/)

Comment: The OP doesn't want that. Your h1 change back to default color once another one is pressed.

Comment: I understand that. What you are understanding?

Answer (score 3):

P tag is inside an H3 tag. to change the css of the parent H3, you have to use jquery parent function:

```
$('p').on('click', function() { 
    $(this).parent('h3').css('color', 'red');
});
```

this way it works for all Ps and H3s